# How can I create a PC like Million Ants?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation

In a *Pathfinder* game I'd like to play a PC like [Million Ants](http://rickandmorty.wikia.com/wiki/Million_Ants) from the television series *Rick and Morty*. This character is defined to be one million ants, and in its world it behaves like a fluid, in where it can change its form, squeeze and change its density. Of course I'm not looking for anything that fancy, I'd just like to be a swarm of ants taking a humanoid shape that can communicate with others.

Can this be done? If so, how (custom race, template...)? If not, what particulars prevent such a PC?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87680/discussion-on-question-by-throkar-how-can-i-create-a-pc-like-million-ants).

Answer (score 11):

There are a couple ways to achieve the goal of having a swarmy-type PC.

The first is the [Swarm Monger](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo-druid-archetypes/swarm-monger/) druid archetype, which lets a druid wild shape into a swarm starting at level 12. Not the same as being a swarm all the time, but is clearly rules legal.

The second is to have your PC use the monster template [Worm that Walks](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/worm-that-walks-cr-2/) from Bestiary 2, which is a hivemind of worms, and there's [locust, ant, and cockroach variants](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/vermin/worm-that-walks-human-conjurer/worm-that-walks-locust/) noted (though not specced out).  This, you'd need GM permission for - it's basically CR=base creature +2, so it's not too crazy, the GM could use the [Other Races](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/) guideline and decide how many levels being a WtW counts as (at least 2, maybe more).

The third is to do some [Race Builder](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/creating-new-races/) work to make it happen.  There are no stock racial traits that map directly to that, and the spells that turn people into swarms are higher level than the "Spell-Like Ability, Greater" trait allows.  But if you just enumerate the specific traits you want your swarminess to have you can race-build fairly easily - if you just want to "look swarmy", that's a freebie as it's just a cosmetic reskin - if you want it to have the equivalent of a bite attack and a special movement (burrowing?) in addition you can price it out using those existing traits.

See also: [How do you make new playable races?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53944/how-do-you-make-new-playable-races)

Answer (score 1):

Another published option that could fit what you are looking for is an [Oozemorph Shifter](http://aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Shifter%20Oozemorph) from *Ultimate Wilderness*.

It behaves like a fluid, in where it can change its form, squeeze and change its density.

The Oozemorph, from level 1, gets **Compression (Ex)** and **Fluidic Body (Su)** abilities that allow it to squeeze and generally behave as a pile of goo. With the level progression, the oozemorph learns to stay in the humanoid form longer during the day, as well as assume more bestial shapes later on.

It wouldn't be the same as being a *swarm*, since you'll be considered an *ooze* instead - but it is not different mechanically very much (both are pretty much defined by immunity to critical hits and flanking ) and can be re-flavored with no additional effort.