# Where can I find the rules for creating a character that is the child of a human and a monster?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, races, optional-rules

Some time ago, I saw someone mention making a monstrum when asked about creating monster races. Supposedly it is a PC that is the child of a human and a monster, or something like that. I was wondering where I can find the rules for doing so. For example, a Half [Yuuki-Onna](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/yuki-onna/). It's like a half-elf, but instead of an elf, the non-human parent was a monster. The idea is that some of the monster's abilities would be passed down to the offspring but not all and in a weaker variation.

This is not a duplicate of [this question about making new playable races](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/53944/52137), because that post is asking about making new races in general, not specifically tailored to monster-human offspring like mine is. If this is a duplicate then please explain to me where the overlap is located because for the life of me I can't see it. In the linked post I see creating a monster race and advance race guidelines (linked twice) neither of which answer my question.

Comment: Those are fusions not actual hybrid offspring.

Comment: @NeilSlater Why don't you make that an answer? I mean, *Exactly what you want doesn't exist, but close to it is this process* sounds like an adequate answer to me.

Comment: A new race is a new race. It doesn't matter that the background is a fusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The person I saw mention this concept used the guidelines for [creating a Monstorin](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/3rd-party-races/northwinter-press/monstorin/) (from *Mystical: Kingdom of Monsters* by Northwinter Press), but reflavored it to be the child of a human and a monster.

I actually found the guy; he basically said to follow those guidelines, but to use primarily the traits from the non-monster race and add one or two from the monster race, lowering them in strength if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [Templates](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/); these give any creature the abilities of a monster(type). for the Yukki-onna, i'd think the [Ghost](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/ghost/) is the most appropriate.

The rulebook recommends a player with this template to be 2 class levels behind the rest of the party (so this character will be level 1, and the rest of the party should be around level 3)